# Не отображаeтся картинка

Tags: java, android, xml

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Картинка вообще ни откуда не отображается. Пробовал взять из ресурса `load(R.drawable.mimiony)`, по-любому не отображается.... И приложение вылетает, с ошибкой " Приложения остановлено ". А в логе ничего, нет никаких ошибок.

Активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageview;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

        String uri = "http://d3.files.namba.kg/files/167653712";


        Picasso.with(this).load(uri).into(imageview);

        Log.e("WTF", "test " + uri );



    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.nurkan.picassotest2.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:text="show"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Делайте дополнения, редактируя сам вопрос (кнопка "править" под вопросом), а не в комментариях к нему. Так не бывает, чтобы при вылете из приложения в логе об этом ничего не отображалось.

Comment: https://ok.ru/profile/556253399154/pphotos/853266326130  ... вот изображение .... там на нажатие кнопки в логе просто ссылка появляется а в ImageView не отображается .... вроде все понятно обьяснил

Comment: @pavlofff Подскажите что делать ???

Comment: Можно попробовать поставить брейк поинт на строчке с Picasso и запустит в режиме дебега.

Comment: @Valery Ponomarenko  спасибо за ответ .... но я не не знаю как вставить брейк поинт,  и где находиться  режим дебега.(можете показать примеры я в гугле не нашел) .. просто я только начал учиться уже прошло  месяц .... Нам дали задание чтоб добавляли с picasso на Adapter(lisrview, Baseadapter и .т.д) .... И вот я как я открыл проект хотул посмотреть работаетли Picasso , ,, и тут такое ошибка...

Comment: @Nurkan, если вы в андроид студио, поставить брейк поинт можно, кликнув по области серого цвета слева от кода. Должна появится красная точка. Запустить приложение в отладочном режиме можно с помощью Shift+F9.

Comment: Вылетает сразу при запуске или после нажатия кнопки? Если после нажатия, то попробуйте другой context передавать. Ну а если при запуске, то может вы вообще забыли объявить активность в манифесте

Comment: Как я мог забыть его объявить в манифесте .... Проблема решена Спасибо вам Аксенов Владимир .                                                         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">

    </uses-permission>